# How to turn on DDL transactional support?

Tags: java, version-control, flyway

I just started using flywaydb and just for a test tried with create and insert queries and fired the migrate but it ignored all my create table scripts :(

I used -X option for debug and found a strange line 
`DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: false`

Seems if i made it true, it will work.

Does anyone faced this issue, if yes how to get rid of this?
i have did this on new schema, with clean-init-migrate
Full stacktrace below:

```
[ec2-user@ec2 flyway]$ ./flyway -X clean
/usr/bin/tput
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
Database: jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/test (MySQL 5.5)
DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: false
DEBUG: Schema: test
DEBUG: Cleaning schema `test` ...
Cleaned schema `test` (execution time 00:00.025s)

[ec2-user@ec2 flyway]$ 
[ec2-user@ec2 flyway]$ ./flyway -X init
/usr/bin/tput
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
Database: jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/test (MySQL 5.5)
DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: false
DEBUG: Schema: test
DEBUG: Schema `test` already exists. Skipping schema creation.
Creating Metadata table: `test`.`schema_version`
DEBUG: Found statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE `test`.`schema_version` (
    `version_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `installed_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `version` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `script` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    `checksum` INT,
    `installed_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `installed_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `execution_time` INT NOT NULL,
    `success` BOOL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
DEBUG: Found statement at line 30: ALTER TABLE `test`.`schema_version` ADD CONSTRAINT `schema_version_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
DEBUG: Found statement at line 32: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_vr_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`version_rank`)
DEBUG: Found statement at line 33: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_ir_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`installed_rank`)
DEBUG: Found statement at line 34: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_s_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`success`)
DEBUG: Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE `test`.`schema_version` (
    `version_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `installed_rank` INT NOT NULL,
    `version` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `script` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    `checksum` INT,
    `installed_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `installed_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `execution_time` INT NOT NULL,
    `success` BOOL NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
DEBUG: Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE `test`.`schema_version` ADD CONSTRAINT `schema_version_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
DEBUG: Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_vr_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`version_rank`)
DEBUG: Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_ir_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`installed_rank`)
DEBUG: Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX `schema_version_s_idx` ON `test`.`schema_version` (`success`)
DEBUG: Metadata table `test`.`schema_version` created.
DEBUG: MetaData table `test`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
Schema initialized with version: 1
[ec2-user@ec2 flyway]$ ./flyway -X migrate
/usr/bin/tput
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.0

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
Database: jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/test (MySQL 5.5)
DEBUG: DDL Transactions Supported: false
DEBUG: Schema: test
DEBUG: Spring Jdbc available: false
DEBUG: Validating migrations ...
DEBUG: Scanning for filesystem resources at '/home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../sql' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql')
DEBUG: Scanning for resources in path: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../sql (/home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../sql)
DEBUG: Found filesystem resource: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../sql/V1__cr_tbl.sql
DEBUG: Found filesystem resource: /home/ec2-user/installables/flyway-3.0/bin/../sql/V2__Add_people.sql
Validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.032s)
DEBUG: Schema `test` already exists. Skipping schema creation.
DEBUG: Locking table `test`.`schema_version`...
DEBUG: Lock acquired for table `test`.`schema_version`
Current version of schema `test`: 1
Migrating schema `test` to version 2
DEBUG: Found statement at line 1: insert into PERSON (ID, NAME) values (1, 'Axel')
DEBUG: Found statement at line 2: insert into PERSON (ID, NAME) values (2, 'Mr. Foo')
DEBUG: Found statement at line 3: insert into PERSON (ID, NAME) values (3, 'Ms. Bar')
DEBUG: Executing SQL: insert into PERSON (ID, NAME) values (1, 'Axel')
DEBUG: Rolling back transaction...
DEBUG: Transaction rolled back
ERROR: Migration of schema `test` to version 2 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
DEBUG: MetaData table `test`.`schema_version` successfully updated to reflect changes
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 1: insert into PERSON (ID, NAME) values (1, 'Axel')
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:91)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:287)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:285)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:285)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:46)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:207)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:864)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:811)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1171)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:811)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:120)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:88)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.PERSON' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:235)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:89)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply means your DB does not support DDL transactions. Use a different like PostgreSQL, DB2 or SqlServer if you need that.

Now as to why your scripts are not being picked up, this is impossible to tell from your question.

Start with a getting started tutorial and once successful, adapt it to your project.

Comment: Hi Axel, i am using mysql and this problem i am getting from getting started tutorial.

Comment: If you follow the steps exactly it works. Issue a flyway clean and try again.

Comment: @alex-fontaine, i did it as you said from [This link](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline.html) except i am using mysql. init and clean is working but for migrate its ignoring the V1__cr_tbl.sql, i have updated the full stacktrace in original question

Comment: Skip the init. It is for existing dbs only.

Comment: still it failed :( , i found the process works for H2 database but failing for MySQL.